# Interpunktion bei "und so weiter" vs. "und andere mehr"

Tags: punctuation, abbreviation

Warum wird mit Hinblick auf die Interpunktion *und so weiter* mit *usw.* abgekürzt, dagegen jedoch *unter anderem mehr* mit *u.a.m.*?

Comment: "unter anderem mehr" ist kein üblicher Ausdruck. Die Abkürzung "u. a. m." steht für "und and[e]re mehr, und and[e]res mehr". Bei solchen mehrteiligen Abkürzungen wird zwischen den einzelnen Elementen nach dem Punkt ein Zwischenraum gesetzt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Abkürzungen ohne Punkt**

> ZDF, PKW, StVO, UNHCR, UdSSR

Kein Punkt wird verwendet, wenn bei der Aussprache die Buchstabennamen aneinander gereiht werden.

> Zett-De-Ef, Pe-Ka-We, Es-Te-Vau-O, U-En-Ha-Ce-Er, U-De-Es-Es-Er

Physikalische Einheiten werden ebenfalls ohne Punkt abgekürzt

> m, s, V, A
> Meter, Sekunde, Volt, Ampere

---

**Abkürzungen mit Punkt**

> u.a., d.h., i.d.R.

Wenn anstelle der geschriebenen Abkürzung der vollständige Begriff ausgesprochen wird, kommt beim Abkürzen der Punkt zum Einsatz

> unter anderem, das heißt, in der Regel

Das gilt auch, wenn von den abgekürzten Wörtern mehrere Buchstaben in der Abkürzung sichtbar bleiben

> ges.gesch., Dr., Ing., Jhd.
> gesetzlich geschützt, Doktor, Ingenieur, Jahrhundert

---

**Ausnahmen**

Es gibt ein paar Abkürzungen, bei denen anders als üblich verfahren wird

- etc. (statt "et c." oder "e.c.") für "et cetera"
- usw. (statt "u.s.w.") für "und so weiter"
- svw. (statt "s.v.w.") für "so viel wie"
- gdw. (statt "g.d.w.") für "genau dann, wenn"

Diese Ausnahmen haben sich allesamt durch häufigen Gebrauch etabliert.

Comment: Die Ausnahmen sind relativ heterogen - "usw." wird stets der volle Begriff ausgesprochen, während bei "etc." wahlweise die einzelnen Buchstaben oder der volle Begriff vorgelesen werden. Die Abkürzung "svw." ist mir dagegen in meinem ganzen Leben noch nie bewusst begegnet und ich wüsste erst einmal nichts damit anzufangen, weshalb ich ihr ehrlich gesagt den Anspruch des "häufigen Gebrauchs" absprechen möchte. Stammt das aus einer bestimmten Fachsprache, so wie "gdw." außerhalb der Mathematik (so mein Eindruck) ja auch eher nicht allgemein gebräuchlich ist?

Answer (score 1):

Die Regel für Abkürzungen aus mehreren Wörtern lautet, dass zwischen den Anfangsbuchstaben ein Punkt und ein schmales Leerzeichen steht. Es ist also besser, für *und so weiter* zu schreiben: *u. s. w.* Diese Schreibweise ist durchaus möglich und nicht falsch, auch wenn man sie nicht oft findet.

Anmerkung zur Frage: *u.a.m.* sollte nach dieser Regel *u. a. m.* sein.

Quellen:

https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/usw.

https://www.wortbedeutung.info/u._s._w./